# filling a column of data grid using another column

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

[image]

I'm going to create a table in C# windows form. this table have to column for date : Gregorian Date and Persian Date. 
Gregorian date column is filled by a stored procedure from a SQL database.
I have below function which converts a Gregorian date to Persian Date:

```
public string miladitoshamsi(DateTime _date)
{
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(pc.GetYear(_date).ToString("00"));
sb.Append("-");
sb.Append(pc.GetMonth(_date).ToString("00"));
sb.Append("-");
sb.Append(pc.GetDayOfMonth(_date).ToString("00"));
return sb.ToString();
}
```

I'm trying this code in formload event to fill Persian date column. but it is null yet.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Grd.RowCount-1 ; i++)
        {
            DateTime bdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Grd.Rows[i].Cells["GregorianDate"].Value);
            string s = miladitoshamsi(bdate).ToString();
            Grd.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = s.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(s);
        }
```

when i use messagebox it will return correct Persian Dates. But It cannot fill Data grid Persian Date column.

Comment: Is the Persion Date column of type string?

Comment: It's Column Type is exactly "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn".

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your Form_Load event handler to make sure that (1) it is called, (2) Grd.RowCount is not zero?

Comment: not break point. but i tested it by messagebox. it is ok by message box. you can connect to my computer by team wiewer if it is possible for you.

Answer (score 1):

`Grd.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value` is an `int`, not a `Date`.

You mean `Grd.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value`.

Comment: RightToLeft Property for Data Grid View is True. so Cells[0] is correct.

Comment: You really need to mention things like that in your question.

Comment: Also, if your miladitoshamsi function returns a string, why do you convert it to a string again, and then convert that value to a string yet again in the last line?

Comment: thanks for your helps. but i think Tosting() is ineffective here.

Comment: That is what I'm saying.

Comment: So using or not using it has not any difference. i can remove it later. i need a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set formula expression property of PersianDate column to "[GregorianDate]".
This will fill all the values automatically.

Comment: can you explain more please ? I cant find this Property

Comment: DataTable.Columns["PersianDate"].Expression="[GregorianDate]";